# loop through array of chars not working - Java

Tags: java

am working on a simple console menu and I cannot for the life of me get the menu within the getValidChoice() method to choose any character but the first one in the array.  For any character other than 'A' I'm getting the "Invalid Selection" message.  What am I doing wrong?  Below is the code:

Cheers,

```
class Menu {
    private String[] options;
    public Menu(String[] options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("\t***** Property Sale System Menu *****\n");
        System.out.println("A. " + options[1]);
        System.out.println("B. " + options[2]);
        System.out.println("C. " + options[3]);
        System.out.println("D. " + options[4]);
        System.out.println("X. " + options[0] + "\n");
        System.out.println("Enter your selection");
    }
    public char getValidChoice() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice;
        choice = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        char[] menuChoices = {'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'X', 'x'};
        for(int i = 0; i < menuChoices.length; i++) {
            while(choice != menuChoices[i]) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Selection: " + choice + "\n");
                display();
                choice = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            }
        }
        return choice;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to walk through the logic of your code, line by line, and you'll see your error.

Comment: @fiixed select the answer that helped you, if any.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work, there is no need to create a loop:

```
if(Arrays.asList(menuChoices).contains(choice)){
      //the array contains the choice.
}
```

Take a look at the `Arrays` class documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: @fiixed select this or any other as the 'selected' answer, if they helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your nested loops are confusing you.  Try simplifying things with a new method

```
private boolean isValidChoice(char choice) {
    // Put your for loop in here
}
```

Now change your while loop to

```
while(!isValidChoice(choice))
```

Change `menuChoices` to an instance variable so that you can initialize it in the constructor and then read it in `isValidChoice`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    while ("AaBbCcDdXx".indexOf(choice) == -1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Selection: " + choice + "\n");
             ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an if statement instead of a while loop, something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < menuChoices.length; i++) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    if(choice != menuChoices[i]) {
        x++;
    }
    elseif(choice == menuChoices[i]) {
        y++;
    }

    if(x == menuChoices.length())
    {
    System.out.println("Invalid Selection: " + choice + "\n");
    display();
    getValidChoice();
    }

    if(y == 1)
        i = menuChoices.length();
}
```

Since you're already running through a for loop to check the input against all the possible options you don't need another while loop within the for loop. As someone else said, look at the logic of your code and you will see the mistake. I think what I just wrote up should work, but it will probably need a little editing. The math should check out, but I'm rusty on my java and wrote this code in this little box so I might have some syntax off.

Hope this helps!